# Display all possible categories in an Excel pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am using a pivot table to count the number of loans that a certain state has in a certain category. For example:

```
Label                                    Count
Arizona                                  50
    Payment on time                      25
    Payment delayed one month            15
    Payment delayed two months or more   5
```

This means that Arizona has 50 loans, from which 25 are on time, 15 have a slight delay and 5 have a serious delay. Unfortunately, there are certain states that have no loans in a given category and I would like the pivot table to display a zero in one such case.

For example, I would like to go from this:

```
Label                                    Count
Texas                                    50
    Payment on time                      45
    Payment delayed one month            5
```

To this:

```
Label                                    Count
Texas                                    50
    Payment on time                      45
    Payment delayed one month            5
    Payment delayed two months or more   0
```

In essence, I want every state to display all three categories: On time, 1 month delay and 2+ months delayed. Even if they have no loans in either one of those categories.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Open the pivot-table Options and in the "Layout & Format" tab; look at the "Format" section; Check the "For Empty Cells"  box; enter "0" into the text box.  Select "OK."  You might also want to select the "Field Settings" and then select the "SHow items with no data" box.

Comment: Thank you Sam. Entering a 0 in the empty cell box option didn't help. Selecting "Show items with no data" was the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize for posting something with such an easy fix. Here's how I managed it.

I went into the fields popup window and selected:

> Rows -> Field settings -> Design and Layout -> Show items with no data

The pivot table now display all three categories for every state.

Thanks for your help anyway.